# Android Studio programmatically check a Checkbox and call its OnCheckedChange

Tags: android, checkbox

Can I programmatically check a `checkbox` and make it **call whatever it is coded to do** once checked or unchecked?

For example, if I have a checkbox like this

```
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You checked the checkbox!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You unchecked the checkbox!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

And then would've called

`checkBox.setChecked(true);`

my checkbox would appear checked but it wouldnt make the toast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do any of the following

 1. Create the listener object separate and call it manually when you call `setChecked`

 2. Extract the method for implementation of `onCheckedChanged` and call it manually on your change.

Answer (score 2):

As the name suggest `setOnCheckedChangeListener`, it only calls your callback if the checkbox value actually changes.

So if it's already checked (true), and then you call `checkbox.setChecked(true)`, the value hasn't changed, so your callback won't be called.

Try to do `checkbox.setChecked(false)`, and it should be working correctly.

That's my best guess, without seeing the rest of your code / xml.

Comment: I mean if it is unchecked, and i call setChecked(true), it wont call the onCheckedChange method. But I guess that's just how it works according to the below comments, thanks though

Answer (score 1):

Android widgets' click or touch events are not simulated. you can change states of of widgets like disabling ,enabling ,checked or unchecked programmatically but todo any task when state changes , you have to change their states manually by touching on that widget.

Answer (score 0):

```
   checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {

                             Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You checked the checkbox!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            } else {

                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You unchecked the checkbox!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


        }

    });
```

Just Cheked it. it will work for me.

Comment: Did you call it via setChecked or by clicking the checkbox?

Comment: By clicking on checkbox

Comment: if it is not working you can also try checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {});

Comment: It works when i click the checkbox, but it doesn't if i set it checked or unchecked programmatically

Comment: No, it's inflated programmatically in a PercentRelativeLayout thats in another PercentRelativeLayout that is inside a ScrollView. This should not affect the functionality though.

Comment: Just try it in your xml file android:checked="true"

Comment: That would just set my checkbox to appear checked

Answer (score 0):

if you add checkboxes in LinearLayout (let's call it checkLayout) like this :

```
val widget = AppCompatCheckBox(checkLayout.context)
    val params = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )
    widget.tag = "something you can specify later"
    checkLayout.addView(widget)
```

the code for get the selected checkbox is like this:

```
checkLayout.children.forEach { cb ->
 if(cb is AppCompatCheckBox && cb.isChecked){
    // here you have your checkbox and by tag maybe you can do whatever you want
  }
}
```

and for dynamic added RadioButton you can add them in RadioGroup (let's call it radioLayout) and get the selected like :

```
val rb: AppCompatRadioButton? = radioLayout.findViewById(radioLayout.checkedRadioButtonId)
if(rb.tag == "something"){
  //your code here
}
```